# sync iis6 by Microsoft Web Deploy V2

Tags: deployment, web

**I got** 
Info: Using ID '05fd773b-ed96-44ca-a51f-9733acc80e10' for connections to the remote server.
Error Code: ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE
More Information: Could not connect to the destination computer ("saminsite65m"). On the destination computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Deployment Agent Service") is started.
Error: Object of type 'webServer60' and path '' cannot be created.
Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
Error count: 1.
**when I run command** 
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -disableLink:ContentExtension -enableLink:AppPool -enableLink:AppPoolExtension -enableLink:CertificateExtension -enableLink:FrameworkConfigExtension -enableLink:HttpCertConfigExtension -source:webserver60,computername=SAMINSITE65M -dest:package="J:\Backup\Backup_20120821095049\IIS\IIS.zip",encryptPassword=rwxsb3mo.ql5 -disableRule:IISConfigFrom64To32
in cmd.
**I don't know why.Thanks for you help.**